# If a prisoner runs for President and wins, do they stay in prison while elected?

Tags: united-states, president, prison

It's possible for a U.S. citizen to run for President while in prison, as with
[Eugene Debs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_V._Debs#Presidential_elections).

Suppose a prisoner runs and wins. Let's also suppose that the crimes in for which the prisoner is serving time for are undisputed and terrible, but for some reason the public generally finds that prisoner better than any alternatives.

Now elected, does the prisoner stay in prison and attempt to fulfill their official duties from a cell (not as unfeasible at it used to be if we permit the usage of computer networking)? Can they pardon themselves and walk free? Would they go on parole for four years?

Comment: Inspired by reading a summary from 2000 of the [OLC's opinions](https://www.justice.gov/sites/default/files/olc/opinions/2000/10/31/op-olc-v024-p0222_0.pdf) on whether sitting Presidents are (at least temporarilly) immune from criminal prosecution.

Comment: We'll answer that question when we get there. Lots of hypotheticals that are unlikely to ever happen have no definitive answer in American law.

Answer (score 36):

Whether a President can pardon themselves is somewhat open for debate. No-one has tried it, and it's not explicitly allowed or disallowed. The other and more likely occurrence would be that the vice president takes over until the president is no longer in jail, pursuant to the [25th amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-fifth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Section_4:_Declaration_by_vice_president_and_principal_officers).

Presumably a vice president would pardon in such a situation, this would be the way an elected president would get out of jail. It's also possible that the president would be allowed accommodations to serve in jail or be allowed to serve their sentence in the white house. These option would require some approval from courts or prison wardens, but would likely be granted to a president. The need to always have a president would likely drive the 25th amendment option to be invoked before accommodations could be put in place.

Comment: Should mention the caveat about having to be in federal custody.

Comment: The situation is different if they are incarcerated by one of the states, vs the federal government.  Most prisoners in the U.S. are held under state authority, not federal.

Comment: To clarify what Dandavis and RBarryYoung are hinting at, some people think Presidential Pardons can be given for any crime. In reality, they are [Federal Pardons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_pardons_in_the_United_States), so if you're incarcerated by one of the states, you're not in federal custody and the President can't pardon you.

Comment: It's legally simpler for the president to be pardoned by a state governor rather than having to pardon themself (assuming the state constitution allows pardons), so perhaps better to be in state rather than federal jail, at least if you have a sympathetic governor.

Answer (score 27):

This would be most exceptional.  There is no precedent, and the how matters would play out would depend in the nature of the elected person, the nature of the crime, the make-up of Congress and many other details:

For example, suppose that John Brown, instead of being executed was incarcerated, and then elected to the Presidency by a (much more radical) republican college of electors.  He could justifiably claim that the election was a vindication of his radical abolitionist stand and that he should be released (although as he was convicted under Virginian law, he couldn't pardon himself)

A president-elect who is found guilty between election day and the inauguration may find themselves an embarrassment to their party. If you lose the support of your own party, you don't last long in a system in which you can be removed by a super-majority vote in the Senate, as Nixon found.

The situation in which a person, incarcerated for a crime with no political aspect, is elected president seems unbelievably far fetched. In such a hypothesis, it is pure speculation as to what would happen next.

Comment: We got so far as a previously sentenced person got one third of the vote for Congressional office. (If I recall correctly, conviction happened between winning the primary and running in the general, but I could have it backwards.)

Comment: There are most likely precedents, just not in the USA.

Comment: I think in the current political climate, even a convicted felon would not lose enough support in the Senate to be removed from office.

Comment: Yes, this answer was written in a different era.

Answer (score -1):

There are often no obstacles for the prisoner to become a candidate:

> The Constitution lists only three qualifications for the Presidency — the President must be at least 35 years of age, be a natural born citizen, and must have lived in the United States for at least 14 years ([source](https://www.whitehouse.gov/about-the-white-house/our-government/the-executive-branch/)).

But, of course, being convicted felon for theft or the like harms enough the reputation to make the winning chances slim. **Unless maybe imprisonment is seen as unfair and politically related**. If it is about [Chelsea Manning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelsea_Manning), [Daniel Drayton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearl_incident), [John C. Frémont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_C._Fr%C3%A9mont), [William Lyon Mackenzie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Lyon_Mackenzie) or somebody the like, being them candidates is not completely out of place and they may collect some votes. Supporting groups are likely to do the election rally for them.

Some kinds of crime may be incompatible with the President position as [happened in Lithuania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolandas_Paksas#President_of_Lithuania), but not many.

The president is unlikely to stay in prison. The likely cases are mostly when the person has become a hero for going into prison, so if not by letter, than by sense the judgement is likely to be revised and cancelled by the higher law court, that happened to all the example persons listed. If for some reason it is legally problematic, the President has right to release a prisoner from serving the jail statement in most cases (not all). Nowhere is written one cannot apply this to himself and this would be fair, as the voters handed the mandate to him.

Comment: There is a problem with: *the President has right to release any prisoner*. The presidential pardon power does not include release from imprisonment for violation of state laws.

Comment: When for what the President can pardon? I was under impression, more or less for any crime.

Comment: [Why is the president unable to grant a pardon for State offenses?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/249/26455)

Comment: [Why doesn't the Presidential Pardon power extend to State Crimes?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/35914/26455).

Comment: This is good to know. Striking through.

Comment: (Apologies for the brief deletion of your post due to me having clumsy fingers that hit the wrong link.)